# LoadBalancerFeignClient and SSLSocketFactory

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

If I want to use a custom `SSLSocketFactory` for the Feign client (e.g. `TrustingAllSSLSocketFactory`) do I need to override the `LoadBalancerFeignClient` bean or it can be achieved via a configuration. For example Ribbon has `ribbon.CustomSSLSocketFactoryClassName=com.netflix.http4.ssl.AcceptAllSocketFactory` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadBalancerFeignClient` is a wrapper around a standard `feign.Client`. If you are using Apache or Ok Http it is enough to make a custom `HttpClient` or `okhttp3.OkHttpClient` bean respectively. If you are using the default create a bean of `new feign.Client.Default(SSLSocketFactory, HostnameVerifier)`.